# Why the operator NOT increase my net salary?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to calculate salaries and have a problem determining the tax as follows.

The first 60,000 dollars gross salary is not taxed. On the part of the gross salary in between 60,000 dollars and 100,000 dollars, paid 20% taxes while on a part of the gross salary over 100,000 dollars pays tax of 25%. Write a program that calculates the net salary (salary after tax deduction) for the entered gross salary (salary before tax).

In the first if I set two conditions. That the salary is less than the first limit and must not be equal to zero or less than zero. Under this condition, the net salary should be equal to the gross salary. However the net salary is always higher than the gross salary while the NOT operator is there.

When I delete the NOT operator then everything is fine. Problem is why the NOT operator increases the value of my net salary?

Here is the code

```
const double s0 = 0;// s0, s1 and s2 are tax percentages
        const double s1 = 0.2;
        const double s2 = 0.25;

        const double border1= 60000;
        const double border2 = 100000;
       
        double neto_salary;

        Console.WriteLine(" Enter your bruto sallary ");

        double bruto_salary = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if ( (bruto_salary<border1) && (bruto_salary !<=0) )   //NOT operator on this line
        {
            neto_salary = bruto_salary * (1 - s0);
            Console.WriteLine(" Your salary is {0} $ ", neto_salary);
        
        
        }
        else if ((bruto_salary>border1) && (bruto_salary<border2) )
        {
              neto_salary = border1 + (bruto_salary - border1) * (1 - s1);
            Console.WriteLine(" Your salary is {0} $ ", neto_salary);
        }

        else
        {

            neto_salary = border1 + (border2 - border1) * (1 - s1) + (bruto_salary - border2) * (1 - s2);
            Console.WriteLine(" Your salary is {0} $ ", neto_salary);
        }
```

Comment: i do not see any `NOT` in your code, so how should i begin to guess where your problem is?

Comment: It's going to be some conditional logic, the only NOT operator I saw `!<=0` looked a bit funny, you can state that easier with `>0`

Comment: @Downvoter, give the developer a chance, they've almost done everything right.

Comment: Does C# have a `!<=` comparison operator? I don't think so.

Comment: !<=0 this is what makes me problem :D

Comment: maybe you want `>`

Comment: `!<=0` is likely the same as `>` (along as nullability isn't an issue, and it isn't in that code).

Comment: I want to write that bruto salary must not be less than or equal to zero

Comment: So it must be > 0 - they are different ways of saying the same thing (assuming `bruto_salary` is not `null`, and in your specific code it can't be `null`).

Comment: [Comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators)

Comment: Okay that is not problem. I understand that. But I don´t understand why the value is increasing. Is it some hidden function of the NOT operator. I'm a beginner, so it's not very clear to me

Comment: The short answer is that `!<=` doesn't do what you think it does (see the answer below).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that:

```
bruto_salary !<= 0   // salary not less than or equal to zero.
```

is valid C# syntax, the way to do that would be:

```
! (bruto_salary <= 0)   // not (salary less than or equal to zero).
```

But, since that's equivalent to:

```
bruto_salary > 0   // salary greater than zero.
```

I'd opt for that instead.

---

As an aside, I suspect the expression `bruto_salary !<=0` is actually being treated as `bruto_salary! <= 0`, where `!` is the postfix null-forgiving operator, introduced in [`C# 8`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8).

In a *run-time* context<sup>(a)</sup>, `x!` just evaluates as `x` so your statement really means the totally opposite sense from what you wanted:

```
bruto_salary <= 0
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Nullable checking is a compile time thing that performs static analysis on your code to discover certain problems. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types) for more detail.

Comment: Wait, does this operator actually exist in other programming languages? What's the point of it?

Comment: @41686d6564 nothing it's to make things 'easier' and more natural language, but should never be used as even in natural languages double-negatives confuse the meaning.

Comment: @41686d6564: if you mean `!<=`, no, I've never seen it.

Comment: Wow, I never knew about the postfix `!` operator... I guess it will bring many new questions to stackoverflow once it becomes "mainsteam" :)